# Bootstrap span inside a span

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, row, html

I have some difficulties to understand how put span inside span with bootstrap.

I want to have one block centered, with inside :

-One row with inside :
    -One block at left (span6)
    -One block at right (span6)

-One row with inside : 
    -One button centered (span 6 offset3)

You could see the problem here : 
http://jsfiddle.net/UBTv4/18/

```
<div class='row'>
<div class='span6 offset3'>
    <div class='well'>
        <h2>Title</h2>      
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='span6'>
                    <p class="lead">Bloc left : </p>
                </div>              
                <div class='span6'>
                    <p class="lead">Bloc right : </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='span6 offset3'>
                    <input id="play" type="submit" value="play" class="btn btn-primary"/>       
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the problem ?

I want something like that :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is your solution.

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='span6 offset3 well' >  <!-- .well class here instead of inner div -->
            <h2>Title</h2>      
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='span3'> <!-- instead of span6 -->
                        <p class="lead">Bloc left : </p>
                    </div>              
                    <div class='span3'> <!-- instead of span6 -->
                        <p class="lead">Bloc right : </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='row'>
                    <div class='span3 offset3'>  <!-- instead of span6 -->
                        <input id="play" type="submit" value="play" class="btn btn-primary"/>       
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UBTv4/23/

As explanation I'll suggest you to carefully read Nesting column section from this link:

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html

In short description, if you nest row in a span6, the sum of inner row spans should be 6 also (3+3).

Also .well class has some paddings/marings, so you can't you it "between" parent and nested rows/spans.

Comment: Thanks, but If I put juste the row with the play button, it doesn't really work, the button is not perfectly centered :/
See here : http://jsfiddle.net/UBTv4/24/

Comment: It's because you put the button in 4th column of 6. Try to draw the grid on paper and you will see that in the half of row there is a separator between spans, so you can't you an input there. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/UBTv4/26/

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `.row-fluid` instead. This will get your 2 .span6 is one row.

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/UBTv4/22/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use pull-right and pull-left to make the respective blocks move left and right.

```
</div>              
                <div class='span6'>
                    <p class="lead pull-right">Bloc right : </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='span6 offset3'>
                    <input id="play" type="submit" value="play" class="btn btn-primary"/>       
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the code here:http://jsfiddle.net/UBTv4/18/